# Diagonal convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(x_r)$ be a bounded sequence of points in $X$ and  $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions on $C(X)$ convergent pointwise to $f \in C(X)$. And so for each point $x_r$, the sequence $(f_n(x_r))$ converges to $f(x_r)$. Suppose that $f(x_r)=a$ for each $r$. Is it possible to prove that $(f_n(x_n))$ converges to $a$?

Comment: Is $x_r$ a subsequence of $x_n$? I assume $f \in C(X)$?

Comment: Oh I see, it's in the title: $x_n \subseteq x_r$.

Comment: Yes $f \in C(X)$ but $(x_r)$ is just a sequence of points. I put the index $r$ to make it different from the index of the sequence of function $(f_n)$.

Comment: What is $X$? ${}{}$

Comment: Assume $X$ is a metric space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. Here is a counterexample.

Let $X = (0, 1)$ and let

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \left(0, 2^{-(n+1)}\right]\\
2^{n+1}x - 1 & x \in \left(2^{-(n+1)}, 2^{-n}\right]\\
3 - 2^{n+1}x & x \in \left(2^{-n},\ 2^{-n} + 2^{-(n+1)}\right]\\
0 & x \in \left(2^{-n} + 2^{-(n+1)},\ 1\right).\end{cases}$$

Note that $f_n$ is piecewise continuous and the one-sided limits exist, agree with each other and the value of $f_n$ at each potential discontinuity, so $f_n \in C(X)$. The graph of $f_n$ is a triangular peak at $2^{-n}$ of height $1$ and width $2^{-n}$. As $n$ increases, the triangular peak gets skinnier and moves to the left. As for each $x \in (0, 1)$ there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{-n} + 2^{-(n+1)} = 3.2^{-(n+1)} < x$, $f_n \to f$ pointwise where $f = 0$.

Now let $x_r = 2^{-r}$. Then $(x_r)$ is a bounded sequence in $X$ and $f(x_r) = 0$ for all $r$. However $f_n(x_n) = f_n(2^{-n}) = 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $f_n(x_n) \to 1 \neq 0$.